# Help establishing restrictions for consistency on a linear system.

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problems, and others similar to it. I can typically solve systems of linear equations, but some give me trouble, especially dealing with unknown constants.

I would really love help trying to understand better the methods of solving these types of problems so I can move forward in my studies more effectively. Onto the problem.

Give restrictions on a, b, and c such that the linear system is consistent.

The system is as follows:

\begin{Bmatrix}
        x - 2y + 4z = a \\
        2x + y - z = b \\
        3x - y + 3z = c \\
        \end{Bmatrix}

I know that the solution is "consistent for all a, b, and c such that 0 = c - a - b" but I have never been able to arrive at the solution entirely on my own.

The closest I've gotten on my own, done just a few minutes before the posting of this, was reaching a point where the system is as follows \begin{Bmatrix}
        x - 2y + 4z = a \\
        5y - 9z = -2a + b \\
        -4z = -a - b + c \\
        \end{Bmatrix}

Unfortunately I'm not totally sure where to go from here, though I can see the beginnings of the solution in equations three. The steps I've taken to reach this point are as follows:

- -2E1 + E2 -> E2
- -3E1 + E3 -> E3
- -E3 -> E3 (Probably superfluous)
- -E2 + E3 -> E3

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any systems of equations work, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: Thank you I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere along the line I screwed up some simple math. The row operations I performed are sound, but the I should not have wound up with 4z. After starting from scratch I realized that my math was off.